# Check if iframe is completly loaded Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, events, iframe, load

Does anyone know how to detect if an iframe is completely loaded (I mean really finished including all ressources).
I know the property contentDocument.readyState but this only gives information if the document is loaded, right. I am looking for something like the property complete for images.

The reason I am buildung a preloader and i want to check if the iframe is loaded. For images i differ between image is completely loaded or can i still attach a load event. I want the same for iframes.

So i am not looking for the load Event.
Thanks for your Support

GREETINGS

Comment: Is the iframe content coming from the same domain as the parent window?

Comment: No coming from a different

Comment: In which case the best you can do is await the `load` event on the iframe: https://jsfiddle.net/85tgbhkq/. Note that this does not mean that all resources have loaded, though, but is the best you will be able to achieve with cross-domain content.

Comment: But if the load event already  fired and i am waiting for that event and will never get a return.